# One Package.json to manage Node & React Dependencies

Tags: node.js, reactjs, package.json

So, I am working on a very rudimentary app using React for front-end and Node for server-side programming. Usually I keep two package.json: one to manage node dependency and the other one to manage react's dependencies.. 
I was wondering if I could just keep one package.json and manage reacts and node dependencies through one package file, since I am using same server to deploy the app.

Comment: If two applications are separate, I would recommend you to have them separate. Both applications might use different packages, so keeping them separate will make them loosely coupled and also light weight.

Comment: That‘s no problem if both (front-/backend) live in the same folder

Answer (score 3):

You can use one to manage both, the reason folks don't is because it it's easier to be sure of which dependencies belong to which application.  Further, depending on how you're building your clientside app, you may need to expose your node_modules as a publicly servable location.  Neither of these are insurmountable, and are more a matter of preference.

Some developers have a strong opinion about directory structure and what is "clean".  It's becoming more common to split server and client code into different code repositories for independently versioning them, in which case it's much easier to track one package.json for each repository.